# adding extra to a Map

Tags: java, class, methods, collections, maps

Hi I am trying to re create a soccer tournament and have been able to create the groups with a map but now would like to add the points to each country. Anyone got any good ideas? please see what i have done already.

```
import java.util.*;

class EuroGroupStages {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {

         Map<String, Set<String>> groupA;
         
//public EuroGroupStages() 
//  {
         groupA = new TreeMap<>();

//  }
         
//public void addCountries(String aGroup)
//  {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String aCountry, aGroup;
        char anAnswer;
        boolean flag = true;
        
        while(flag)
        {
            Set<String> country = new HashSet<>();
            
            System.out.print("Please enter the group name (A-D):");     
            aGroup = keyboard.next();
        
                for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    System.out.print("Please enter a country");
                    aCountry = keyboard.next();
                    country.add(aCountry);
                    
                }

            System.out.print("Do you want to continue? Y/N");
            anAnswer = keyboard.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
                
                if(anAnswer == 'N' || anAnswer == 'n')
                {
                    flag = false;
                }
            groupA.put(aGroup, country);
        }

        System.out.println(groupA);
        
        
        keyboard.close();
//  }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would be better off creating `Group` and `Team` classes. Each `Group` would then contain a `Set`/`List`/... (whatever suits the best) of `Team` objects.

In the `Team` class, you can provide an attribute that contains the points of that team in the group stage.

For your `Group`:

```java
public class Group {
    private String name;
    private Set<Team> teams;

    public Group(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.teams = new TreeSet<>();
    }

    public void addTeam(Team team) {
        teams.add(team);
    }
}
```

For your `Team`:

```java
public class Team {
    private String name;
    private int points;

    public Team(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addPoints(int amount) {
        this.points += amount;
    }
}
```

Example use:

```java
public class EuroGroupStages {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create group B
        Group groupB = new Group("B");

        // Create teams in group B
        Team belgium = new Team("Belgium");
        Team finland = new Team("Finland");
        Team denmark = new Team("Denmark");
        Team russia = new Team("Russia");

        // Add teams of group B to group B
        groupB.addTeam(belgium);
        groupB.addTeam(finland);
        groupB.addTeam(denmark);
        groupB.addTeam(russia);

        // First matches were played, Belgium and Finland won
        belgium.addPoints(3);
        finland.addPoints(3);
    }
}
```

**Note**: I did not run this code, it was written on the fly but should give you some idea of how to solve your problem.